# SQL Create "Admin" right inside SQL Query ( CASE/IF inside WHERE clause)

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-bigquery, case

This is my SQL:

```
WHERE 
CASE 
    WHEN (UC.USER = SESSION_USER() AND UC.full_access = 1) 
    THEN (FROS.IsVoided = false) 
    ELSE (FROS.IsVoided = false AND UC.USER = SESSION_USER()) 
END
```

I need that IF user = to (current session user) and full_access = 1 the display **X** else **Y**, I can provide more code and tables, but from general view, can someone find any common mistakes which I have done?

As alternatively I have this idea:

```
WHERE 
IF(UC.USER = SESSION_USER() AND UC.full_access= 1, FROS.IsVoided = false, FROS.IsVoided = false AND UC.USER = SESSION_USER())
```

WHat is the correct way of using if statement inside **WHERE** clause?

**SOLUTION:**

```
WHERE IF(((SELECT full_access FROM `TABLE` WHERE user = SESSION_USER())= 1), (FROS.IsVoided = false), (FROS.IsVoided = false AND UC.USER = SESSION_USER()))
```

Comment: I see your SQL and I read your text, and the two don't match.  One returns a boolean expression, the other requests `'X'` and `'Y'`.  One refers to `IsVoided`, the other doesn't.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm looking to return X and Y, please read the comment under the first answer, I have explained what I'm looking for. Thank you

Comment: . . You should *fix the question* so it conveys what you really want to do.  Don't assume that a comment on an answer does that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff fixed it.

Comment: A `where` clause handles Boolean logic naturally. Using `if` or `case` inside a `where` clause is almost always a poor design decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 5, 6
), users_access AS (
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com' user, 1 full_access UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@gmail.com', 0
) 
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE 1 = (SELECT full_access FROM users_access WHERE LOWER(user) = LOWER(SESSION_USER()))
OR (0 = (SELECT full_access FROM users_access WHERE LOWER(user) = LOWER(SESSION_USER()))
AND col1 > 2)
```

Result for user1@gmail.com:

```
Row     col1    col2    col3     
1       1       2       3    
2       4       5       6
```

Result for user2@gmail.com:

```
Row     col1    col2    col3     
1       4       5       6
```

Result for user3@gmail.com:

```
Row     col1    col2    col3     
Query returned zero records.
```

Above can be slightly refactored as below (with same behavior for users with full_access = 1 or full_access = 0 or those who are not in list at all)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 5, 6
), users_access AS (
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com' user, 1 full_access UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@gmail.com', 0
) 
SELECT * EXCEPT(access) 
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
  UNNEST([(SELECT full_access FROM users_access WHERE LOWER(user) = LOWER(SESSION_USER()))]) access 
WHERE access = 1
OR (access = 0 AND col1 > 2)
```

Note: `col1 > 2` is just dummy filter that in reality should be whatever filter you have in mind for your case

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is a column in the `SELECT` part of the query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN UC.USER = SESSION_USER() AND UC.full_access = 1 
             THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y'
        END) as what_you_asked_for
```

I don't know how this relates to the code that you have provided.

Comment: I would like to create an admin for the table, so if the user has full_access = 1 then do not apply filer,  if = to 0 then apply filter which will be ( WHERE uc.user = SESSION_USER() )